# C# - EF Repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've made up 2 possible ways for how my EF implementation should interact with my app. The first one is a simple Repository, and the second is a rather dynamic version. Both of those solutions produce the same sql queries according to the sql profiler - so nothing more, nothing less.

Now is my question, is there any perfomance overhead for solution 1 compared to solution 2? - and if yes, does it matter in the long run?

**Solution 1:**

```
public class Repository
{
    public MyContext Ctx = new MyContext();

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>() where T : class
    {
        return Ctx.Set<T>();
    }
}
```

... And the code that calls it:

```
var rep = new Repository();

Console.WriteLine("DEALERS:");
foreach(var dealer in rep.GetAll<Dealer>())
{
    Console.WriteLine(dealer.Name);
}

Console.WriteLine("CARS:");
foreach (var car in rep.GetAll<Car>())
{
    Console.WriteLine(car.CarName);
}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
public class Repository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly MyContext _ctx = new MyContext();
    private readonly IDbSet<T> _dbset;

    public Repository()
    {
        _dbset = _ctx.Set<T>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _dbset;
    }
}
```

... And the code that calls it:

```
var dealerRep = new Repository<Dealer>();
var carRep = new Repository<Car>();

Console.WriteLine("DEALERS:");
foreach(var dealer in dealerRep.GetAll())
{
    Console.WriteLine(dealer.Name);
}

Console.WriteLine("CARS:");
foreach (var car in carRep.GetAll())
{
    Console.WriteLine(car.CarName);
}
```

Comment: OT: Get All/Select All can be pretty expensive if a table has thousands (or tens of thousands) of rows, I'd be conservative in using it without filters/qualifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF is an ORM and already implements the Repository pattern, there is absolutely no need to wrap it in your own repository.

Comment: @Oded - touché... - My problem is that I need some extra functionality - ex. when calling `GetAll()` it should do some other stuff too.

Comment: @BrokenGlass - What exactly? That EF is an ORM? That is implements the Repository pattern? Or that an ORM shouldn't be wrapped in a repository?

Comment: @ebb - I would call that a facade, or service that is _using_ a repository.

Comment: @Oded: the later - there are advantages to having a repository / unit of work on top of EF for testability w/o touching the DB

Comment: @BrokenGlass - As usual, it is a matter of "it depends"... on what you are doing...

Comment: @Oded - I see... and what if you want this extra functionality to apply to all of your services - would you then need to duplicate the code?

Comment: @ebb - I would try to design it so there is no duplication (or as little as possible).

Comment: @Oded - If we leave the fact, that the repository might be overenginnering... is there any perfomance difference between solution 1 and solution 2?

Comment: @ebb - I don't expect that there would be, but your best bet is to benchmark both approaches with your implementation and database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the same set at least twice in each repository,
to see if the two solutions really act the same.

Check profiler on 2nd call and perhaps make changes to data
via another context, between accesses, to make sure behavior is the same.